# Resource not found!! Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I have in my web.php the following routes:

```
Route::get('admin', ['as' => 'admin.login', 'uses' => 'AdminController@login']);
Route::post('admin', ['as' => 'admin.postLogin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@postLogin']);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function () {
    // problem is when I redirect to the following route
    Route::get('admin/transactions', ['as' => 'admin.transactions', 'uses' => 'AdminController@transactions']); 
});
```

and my controller as follow:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){
    //some logic
    return Redirect::to('admin/transactions');
}
```

and the transaction action:

```
public function transactions(){
    dd('ok');
}
```

but I still get Resource not found!! why?

Can anybody help me?

Note!!: I have other routes working fine so I don't think it's an .htaccess problem

**EDIT!!**
here is my middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check() || !Auth::user()->admin) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the middleware `isAdmin`. Can you try removing the middleware group? check if it's working.

Comment: Try This `Route::group(['middleware' => 'isAdmin'], function () {
    Route::get('admin/transactions', AdminController@transactions');
});`

Comment: @aceraven777 the problem is not from the middlware i use it in other routes and works fine, and i did try the route with the problem outside to route::groupe but the problem still exist!!

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya still the same problem.

Comment: maybe check your namespaces for AdminController. this cant be a difficult problem

Comment: i found the problem guys, it was a middleware that run durring every request redercting me and that what rase the Resource not found exeption, Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `Route::middleware`?

```
Route::middleware(['isAdmin'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('admin/transactions', 'AdminController@transactions');
});
```

Comment: @ayoubelmoudni try to use a `return` in AdminController@transactions

Comment: still, it doesn't hit the AdminController@transactions at all